# VBA SUM Dynamic Ranges in column

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub SumColumnDynamic()
    Dim RngSumQ, RngSumQS, RngSumQL, SumRange As Range
    Set RngSumQ = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(, 2)
    Set RngSumQS = Cells.FIND(What:="Quantity").Offset(1, 0)
    Set RngSumQL = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 2)
    Set myRange = Range(RngSumQS, RngSumQL)
    Range("RngSumQL") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(SumRange)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there,
I try to do a dynamic sum in column C this column change because is come from pivot
I have try the code above but I get the error message “runtime error 1004 : Method range of object - 'Global' failed”
I am trying to make as dynamic as possible, first with RngSumQ I find the last empty cell in column C 
With RngSumQS I find the start of the sum range in column C, and with RngSumQL I find the last use cell of the sum range.
 Any idea to solve thiw problem???

Comment: i correct  Set SumRange = Range(RngSumQS, RngSumQL) the proble persist

Comment: Another correction Range("RngSumQ") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(SumRange) the error the same

Comment: This line does not belong, `Range("RngSumQL") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(SumRange)`.  The sum of a range would be a number, not a range.  Your declared ranges are not declared correctly and `SumRange` is never defined.  If you tried `y=WorksheetFunction.Sum(myRange)` you might get a number.

Comment: i correct Set SumRange = Range(RngSumQS, RngSumQL) the problem persist

Comment: I find my answer from Tim Williams here: Sum function in VBA topic in stackoverflow thank you very much Tim!